# C# Base64 string can convert to image but not showing in .rdlc Image controls

Tags: c#, winforms, base64, report, rdlc

I used a library to generate Barcode Bitmap and then convert this to Base64 string. This string works ok, I can convert it back to Image in all online tools I found. But when I put it on an Image control in RDLC report by Convert.FromBase64String(), the Image not showing at all.

Here is [my base64 string](https://notepad.pw/3d24n0xr) (Base64Barcode in _sticker instant)

Then I pass this string to my ReportViewer (connected with my .rdlc report)

```
private void FormPreview_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[]
    {
        new ReportParameter("palletNo", _sticker.PalletNo)              
        new ReportParameter("qrBase64", _sticker.Base64QR, true),
        new ReportParameter("barcodeBase64", _sticker.Base64Barcode, true)
    };

    this.reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
    this.reportViewer.RefreshReport();
}
```

In .rdlc I create an Image control and set the field "Use this image" to:

```
=Convert.FromBase64String(Parameters!barcodeBase64.Value)
```

The TextBox control works fine. But Image controls do not show anything but a white little box with a red X inside.

I've found many solutions on the internet but none of them seems works to me. Is there something that I missed?

I use Visual Studio 2019 Community, .NET Framework 4.5, ZXing library 0.16.4.0, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms 14.0.0.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show a `Base64` string as image in the RDLC report, using report designer:

- Drop an `Image` report control from toolbox.
- Right click on the image and choose *Image Properties*
- Set the image source to `Database`
- Set the MIME type to a suitable value, for example `image/bmp`.
- Set use this field to the image parameter which you have, for example =`Parameters!MyImage.Value`. The parameter type should be `Text`.

Then at run-time, assign the `Base64` string as value of the parameter.

**Note:** When the image source is set to `External`, the value of the parameter should set to an absolute URL and the [`LocalReport.EnableExternalImages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.enableexternalimages?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the report viewer should be set to `true`.

Comment: JFYI, instead of generating the barcode, you may want to rely on a barcode font, [like this](https://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/).

Comment: I used `Embedded` image source in my previous and when I change as your advice, it works perfectly. I can't believe that I spent almost half of the day on this. Thank you so much. And the font is great, wish I know about this sooner :)) Thanks again.

Comment: These steps are working correctly, you save my day . Thank you very much @RezaAghaei